# Suggestion to use layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment

I have 3 views on a screen in android, assume like set of buttons, map, list and another information view. these are all present vertically.

So, if i click on list, map should get updated & also buttons color should change. Some time if i click on button information should display.

In this scenario, is it good to use fragments? or Relative layout?. suggest

Thanks

Comment: use fragments. one for list and other to display map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a Activity that consists of a RelativeLayout, with 3 FrameLayouts inside the RelativeLayout. I would then add Fragments in code, to the FrameLayouts. 1 fragment to each. This way you can easily move the fragments in any way you desire. Sliding menus, top sliding, side sliding, over and under, so easy. So easy if you set it up like this.

When the far left is selected you can shove ther other 2 the right, when the center receives focus slide the left one to the left and right one right, and when the far right one gets focus, slide the other to to the left.

Or you can do top to bottom.
Or you can just have all 3 have equal space, at all times.
Or you can always shove the non-focused ones to the right, left, top, bottom, the possibilities are endless. You can shrink the unfocused 2 to 1/4 size and shove them to one side of the screen, one o top and one on bottom.

See where I'm going?

otherwise do a linearlayout, with 3 framelayouts, and set each framelayout to weight = 1 (may have to toggle a few other options to keep them perfectly even at all times), then add your fragments.

```
    public void swapfragment(int fragId, Bundle args, boolean slide)
    {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        switch (fragId)
        {
        case FRAGID_DEVICE:
            currentFrag = new FragmentDevice();
            currentFrag.setArguments(args);
            ((FragmentDevice) currentFrag).initialize();
            break;
        case FRAGID_NETWORK:
            currentFrag = new FragmentNetwork();
            currentFrag.setArguments(args);
            ((FragmentNetwork) currentFrag).initialize();
            break;
        }

        ft.replace(R.id.flFragHost, currentFrag).commit();
        if (slide)
            slideFragment();
    }

    private void slideFragment()
    {
        final Point displaySize = new Point();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);

        if (isFragmentOut)
        {
            isFragmentOut = false;
            Animation slideOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_out_80);
            AnimationListener listener = new Animation.AnimationListener()
            {

                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
                {
                }

                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
                {
                }

                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
                {
                    int pushback = (int) (displaySize.x * .8f);

                    rlFragHost.clearAnimation();
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams FragContainerParams;
                    FragContainerParams = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) rlFragHost.getLayoutParams();
                    FragContainerParams.setMargins(pushback, 0, pushback * -1, 0);
                    rlFragHost.setLayoutParams(FragContainerParams);
                }
            };
            slideOutAnimation.setAnimationListener(listener);
            rlFragHost.startAnimation(slideOutAnimation);
        }
        else
        {
            isFragmentOut = true;
            Animation slideInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_in_80);
            AnimationListener listener = new Animation.AnimationListener()
            {

                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
                {
                }

                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
                {
                }

                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
                {

                    rlFragHost.clearAnimation();
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams FragContainerParams;
                    FragContainerParams = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) rlFragHost.getLayoutParams();
                    FragContainerParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    rlFragHost.setLayoutParams(FragContainerParams);
                }
            };
            slideInAnimation.setAnimationListener(listener);
            rlFragHost.startAnimation(slideInAnimation);
        }
    }
```

I know this isn't exactly what you need, but it should get you started. this is how I do sliding menus.

Comment: ok, you mean to say keep 3 fragment, align them in a relative layout. use it accordingly. correct?

Comment: Correct. It all depends on what you want, but when I have to do sliding menus for clients, I find this the fastest and easiest way to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of it is personal preference. My particular favorite is the linear layout. You mentioned that you want to present the items vertically, well, just set android:orientation="vertical", put your items in the xml file in order, and there you go. I've never used fragments personally, so I can't speak to their usefulness, but the linear layout has yet to let me down.